# Is there a special common name for goods sold at public events?

Tags: nouns

Is there a special common name for goods sold at public events, such as T-shirts, cups, stationery, etc. being sold at conferences, concerts.

Comment: I don't know if there is an associated word for the merchandise, but the outlets that sell these goods are called *concessions*.

Comment: I always thought that "concessions" were sold at [concession stands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concession_stand), but this is apparently not the case. Interesting.

Comment: Not sure, but I have heard people referring to such items as *goodies*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At music concerts, such items are often collectively called *merch* (short for *merchandise*). It might be appropriate to use the word by extension to refer to similar items sold at other large public gatherings, although I don't know whether *merch* is sufficiently widely known that the average person would know what you're talking about without explanation. Either way, the word *merch* should be considered slang or informal, and therefore not appropriate for formal communication.

When branded items are *given* away at such events, they are typically (in the United States at least) called *swag* collectively, which is also slang/informal.

Comment: I would say that ‘merch’ is common enough for an average person to understand, but ‘swag’ might not be. I had never heard of it in this sense, for example—if someone were to mention such trinkets as swag, I would probably have assumed that they were in fact referring to stolen goods.

Comment: The terms also depend on your country. In my country, swag refers to stolen goods, and I have not heard *merch* before.

Comment: @PaddyLandau - "Swag" in this sense is _meant_ to be a play on the "stolen goods" meaning (stolen goods are the best kind!) but it's also a [backronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backronym) for **[Stuff We All Get](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=swag%20(s.w.a.g.))**.  The most visible giveaway items at conventions are usually the "swag bags" - tote bags to hold the swag you collect at other booths.

Comment: I should have said: "Stuff We All Get" is a backronym for "swag".

Comment: Another informal name for free items given away (at least at computer conferences) is *goodies*.

Answer (score 2):

The word I hear a lot for these types of things (especially if they carry a brand logo) is "merch." Short for "merchandise."

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes these items are also referred to as souvenirs.

Comment: That is not a *special* name for "goods sold at public events". Souvenirs are more generally available in tourist shops worldwide as mementos of holidays/vacations.

Comment: I qualified my answer by including "sometimes" and "also" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[commemorative](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/commemorative) material*

> produced for an important event to help you remember it
>   *a commemorative stamp*

They also could be cal[enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promotional_goods)led

> - promotional merchandise
> - promotional items
> - promotional products
> - promotional gifts
> - advertising gifts

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, especially in a student context, this could be called 'stash'.

> **stash**
>
> Items of clothing, usually aquired whilst at University, baring the name of a club to which the wearer belongs and usually a obscure nickname picked up in Freshers' Week. Every club or team likes to believe that they have the best stash. Highly desirable at universities like Durham, UK.
>
> *Tarquin: "Shall we do a Bailey bar crawl in our Tennis Stash?" 
>
>   Rupert: "Oh golly! That would be delightful!"*

-- [urbandictionary.com](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=stash)